# When using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute, statuscode is not sent to browser

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple .NET Core 2.0 project. Here is the Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}.html");

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller}/{action?}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
  }
```

When I enter an invalid url, /error/404.html is displayed as expected, but the browser gets a 200 status code, instead of the expected 404 status.

What am I doing wrong? Can I not use a static html file as error page?

Comment: UseStaticFiles is likely setting the 200 when it serves the 404.html. you could override it in the event on the options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`you

> Adds a StatusCodePages middleware that specifies that the response body should be generated by re-executing the request pipeline using alternate
>   path.

As path `/error/404.html` exists and works OK, the 200 status is used.

---

You may use the following approach (look into [this article](https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/) for more detailed explanation):

setup action that will return View based on a status code, passed as a query parameter

```
public class ErrorController : Controller  
{
    [HttpGet("/error")]
    public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
    {
        if (statusCode.HasValue)
        {
            // here is the trick
            this.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode.Value;
        }

        //return a static file. 
        return File("~/error/${statusCode}.html", "text/html");

        // or return View 
        // return View(<view name based on statusCode>);
    }
}
```

then register middleware as

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
```

this placeholder {0} will be replaced with the status code integer automatically during redirect.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a bit further. But is it possible to redirect from ErrorController to my static 404.html?

Comment: If it was unclear in my original question, "error" is a directory in "wwwroot", not a controller, and "404.html" is an html file in the wwwroot/error directory.

Comment: @BjarteAuneOlsen: have edited answer so the action now returns a static file instead of view (look into https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3751). You don't
need to use redirect, as you again will see 200 OK => redirect works in the following way: the server sends a 302 code along with a Location header, and the browser requests the new URI specified by the Location header instead.

Comment: The method File(string filepath) doesn't seem to exist in dotnet core, so I'll go back to using a view like you suggest in your first answer.

Comment: @BjarteAuneOlsen right, there is now a [ControllerBase.File(string virtualPath, string contentType)](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1231) method. Just specify "text/html" as a content type.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.