# Handle Errors on Asp.net core6 mvc

Tags: exception, filter, error-handling, asp.net-core-middleware, exceptionhandler

I am studying asp.net core and I need to fix error handling problems.

I have some questions about them

1- should we catch all error types and return specific views each of them? 400 401 403 404 500 and more

2-if yes, which method is the best practice? Middleware or filters or any other? Can you share some samples please?

3-if no, what kind of route should I follow for errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the response codes, it's up to you whether you need to display a different page for each code.

For example, use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` middleware:

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
{
    if (statusCode.HasValue) 
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = statusCode;
        return View("ErrorPage");
    }
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}

[Route("ErrorPage")]
public IActionResult ErrorPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

In ErrorPage.cshtml, you can use `ViewData["Message"]` to get the response code and display different content for it.

Or you can create a view for each response code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374169/18789859).

For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0l).